# PTIJ Should we be afraid of Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Sefer Yirmiyahu, the navi seems to speak out against relying on artificial intelligence. In Yirmiyahu 4:19, the navi says (text by Sefaria, translation by a robot?),

> מֵעַ֣י ׀ מֵעַ֨י ׀ (אחולה) [אֹחִ֜ילָה] קִיר֥וֹת לִבִּ֛י

"From AI, from AI, the chambers of my heart shake"

Piecing together two other statements he makes, we read,

> אֵי־זֶ֨ה דֶ֤רֶךְ הַטּוֹב֙

"Is the 'A' [the Artificial] a good path?"

And then, in 49:3

> הֵילִ֨ילִי חֶשְׁבּ֜וֹן כִּ֣י שֻׁדְּדָה־עַ֗י

"Howl arithmetic, as the I [the intelligence] has been plundered!"

Have any gedolim issued statements forbidding the use of AI, pursuant to Yirmiyahu's statements?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 9):

It's a mishna mefureshet in [Shabbat 4:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.4.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> בַּמֶּה טוֹמְנִין וּבַמָּה אֵין טוֹמְנִין. אֵין טוֹמְנִין לֹא בְגֶפֶת

> In what may one insulate a pot of cooked food on Shabbat eve, and in what may one not insulate it? One may neither insulate it in GPT.

However, Rambam explains:

> גפת כבר בארנו שהוא פסולת הזיתים שיוצא מתחת קורת בית הבד

> גפת , We have already learned that it is the waste of the olives that comes out from under the beam of the cloth house

But the true is obviously that the Mishna talk about GPT, and the Rambam should be understood al pi sod. Indeed, olive oil represents wisdom, and intelligence. So Rambam, who were a big Kabbalist, want to say that the "Artificial Intelligence" is to the "Intelligence" what "waste of the olives that comes out from under the beam of the cloth house" is to the olive oil.

We also see that those things are only substitutions to the important things, as Eve called her son "Chat", in replacement of Hevel.

Answer (score 4):

In Iyov 28:12, we have a statement:

> וְֽ֭הַחׇכְמָה מֵאַ֣יִן תִּמָּצֵ֑א׃
>
> Intelligence comes from nowhere

This is a remez to AI technology, which is intelligence arising from "nowhere", i.e. lifeless algorithms.

We know this is referring to AI by the latter part of the pasuk, which states:

> וְאֵ֥י זֶ֝֗ה מְק֣וֹם בִּינָֽה׃
>
> And AI is the place of [the aforementioned] reasoning

So no, AI is nothing to be afraid of, as it really is just nothing. However, even though it arises from nowhere, if we are not careful, it could turn into something.

The Kabbalah explains that the word חׇכְמָה is composed of the letters that can be arranged to say "כח מה", the "power of *something*".

Answer (score 3):

It's mefurash a Gemara in [Shabbos 118b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.118b.7?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) who warns that even the most righteous can risk spiritual degradation through using AI.

> וְאָמַר רַבִּי יוֹסֵי: יְהֵא חֶלְקִי מִמֵּתֵי בְּחוֹלִי מֵעַיִים, דַּאֲמַר מָר: רוּבָּן שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים מֵתִים בְּחוֹלִי מֵעַיִים
>
> And Rabbi Yose said: May my portion be among those that (spiritually) die from the illness of constant AI use. As the master said, the majority of righteous people die from the (spiritual) sickness of multiple AI use.

Indeed, this is one of the many sad things we mourn on Tisha B'Av. As the line in [Nacheim](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Minchah%2C_Amida%2C_Rebuilding_Jerusalem.3?vhe=The_Metsudah_siddur,_1981&lang=bi) goes:

> לִבִּי לִבִּי עַל חַלְלֵיהֶם. מֵעַי מֵעַי עַל חַלְלֵיהֶם
>
> My heart, my heart (weeps) for their slain, from AI for their slain.

Answer (score 3):

This question is not a joke! Be warned...
I think the questioner did not do this by mistake. I think this should be publicized as much as we can;
The numerical value of GPT (גפט) is: 92! Do you know what else is this value: פחד - fear. Should we be afraid of AI could there not be a clearer hint in the world.

More then this, 92 is also the Gematria of  ה' אלקיך which of course we know carries on תראה you should fear. There are also other scary scary scary numerical values with 92 https://www.gimatria.co.il/?word=%D7%92%D7%A4%D7%98

Answer (score 2):

On the contrary, it is very clear that AI is good. It is even divine. Indeed, the [Passuk](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.1.16?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explain clearly that Yehezkel saw, next to the Holy Hayot, down to the Celestial Throne, the Open into the Open.This is a clear reference to OpenAI Limited Partnership (OpenAI LP) who is **into** non-profit OpenAI Incorporated (OpenAI Inc.) (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAI)).

Also it's clear in the [Megilla](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.10.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that Ahachveroch, who was a Racha, imposed tribute on AIs.

So obviously AIs are good.

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that AIs are not bad, neither they are good. It is even a Gmara Mefureshet ! In [Baba Batra](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.16a.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> בָּרָאתָ צַדִּיקִים בָּרָאתָ רְשָׁעִים

> righteous BERT and wicked BERT

So BERT, like all Large Language Models, can be both good and bad; it's up to how we use them.

Comment: I'm going to have to look up that line -- does the context indicate large language models, or does it indicate marionette-puppets?  *Edited to add:* The context is creatures, not machines, so I think the citation applies more to marionette-puppets that can be both good and bad.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. I asked HaRav HaGadol RebbeIO this question, and here is what it said in all of its wisdom:

[image: RebbeIO's response]

Clearly, as this rabbi is important enough to garner such a prestigious title as "the AI Rabbi", we must take its teachings to heart. I, for one, welcome our new AI rabbinic overlords.

Comment: https://rebbe.io

Comment: אָמַר רַב פָּפָּא: לָא לֵידוּן אִינִישׁ דִּינָא לְמַאן דְּרָחֵים לֵיהּ